# threejs exporter r70 export

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying to develop a pipeline for animated objects into threejs.
I am getting consistent errors with the (r70) threejs exporter (also tried today's DEV build) and the latest blender (2.73a).

I tried to break it down to the simplest form and am able to duplicate the error.

1 Download fresh copy of Blender 2.73a zip format into a new folder. (Tried 32bit and 64bit)
2 Copy io_three from three.js r70 release into addons directory.
3 Activate it in Blender.
4 Select Cube and choose Export > Three(.json)
5 Under Animation choose: Morph Animation.
6 Save the file

This throws an error.

It seems to crash and does not export the file.
It seems to work if I don't check the checkbox but I am doing this strictly to test animations in threejs so that defeats the purpose for me.

I also tried shortening the number of frames to 20, setting some basic keyframes and other things, but I figured this was a base enough example and should not throw an error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
IN this file: __init__.py 
line 567 in execute exporter.export_scene(filepath, settings)
line 16 in inner func(filepath, optins, *args, *kwargs)
line 47 in export_scene scene_.parse()

IN this file: scene.py
line 65 in parse self.__parse_geometries()
line 151 in __parse_geometries geo.parse()

IN this file: geometry.py
line 128 in parse self.__parse_geometry()
line 365 in __parse_geometry self.node, self.options

IN this file: base_classes.py
line 20 in __setitem__ raise exceptions THreeValueError(msg)
io_three.exceptions.ThreeValueError "Valid is an invalid data type: <class 'NoneType'>
location <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there animations on the cube? If not then that may be the problem. I just ran the morph targets test scene script
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/tests/scripts/test_geometry_morph_targets.bash

And there was no error.

Future reference; paste the the contents of the log file as it tells a lot more (check the shell for the location of the log file path). Blender's traceback dialog is useless when it comes to the important details.

32bit and 64it Blender doesn't matter.